# Why does emacs start slowly

Tags: emacs

Recently, I found that my emacs starts slowly. Sometimes the startup process takes 30 seconds, sometimes 3 seconds. I guess this is related to network enviroment. However, emacs -q can always start up quickly.

Comment: You could try [ESUP](https://github.com/jschaf/esup) (also available in MELPA) to find which part of your config file slows down startup.

Comment: Or just bisect your init file manually, to find the culprit.

Comment: I have tried to use esup. However, an error occured, "Process *esup-child* exited abnormally with code 1". My emacs version is 24.5.1, no GUI. And, I also found this closed [issue](https://github.com/jschaf/esup/issues/34).

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Emacs takes unbelievably long to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619870/emacs-takes-unbelievably-long-to-start). Your question is answered there.

Answer (score 1):

This question is like asking "How long is a piece of string". You have not provided anywhere near enough information. Start with telling us which version of emacs and what platform you running on.

You mention that emacs -q starts quickly, so we can assume the slowness is due to your init file. There are a lot of possibilities and no way for us to tell for sure without analysing your init file. However, there are a few things you can do to help identify possible causes.

@Drew's comment about bisecting your init file is a very useful trick to identify the source of a problem in your init file, particularly when trying to track down an error. It can be useful in identifying major contributors to load time when those contributors can be linked to a specific config option or package load etc. It is less useful when the problem is an overly long inefficient init file with too many packages.

Using a profiler as suggested by @legoscia can help identify areas to focus on, but it will still be necessary to interpret and understand what the profiler is telling you.

My suggestions would be to

1. Additional Packages. Since the introduction of package.el and the emacs package archives, I've observed a tendency for some users to get a little carried away and install lots of packages just in case. run C-h p and go through the packages you have installed. If you don't use any or you see ones there which you no longer want or use, remove them. Each additional package (depending on how they are loaded - see below) will increase your startup time by some amount as each package will need to be loaded. Loading packages you don't need or want will slow down startup time.
2. Stuff you don't need or understand. Over time, our init file can grow with stuff and we don't remember why we added it or it can be stuff we have copied from others which we thought we might need and forgot about. Every few months (depending on how often you modify your init - maybe more frequently if you make frequent changes, less if you don't) go through your init file and comment out anything you don't need, don't understand or don't rmember why you added it. Just comment it out, don't delete it. Re-start restart emacs and see if it starts faster and whether features or configuration settings you want/need have gone. If there are, look through the stuff you have commented out and see if anything looks relevant. When you find possible candidates, try to work out what the code is doing (look in the emacs manual, use C-h f and C-h v or C-h m etc to try and work it out. If it relates to a specific package, try M-x customize-package and see if there is built in customization which might give you what you want. Even if you prefer to customize things by hand rather than use emacs' built in customization system, M-x customize-group is a great way to find out what customizations are supported by a package and verify you have variable names correct etc.
3. Learn emacs autoloads. Emacs has this very useful feature called autoload. There are two main ways of loading packages into emacs. The first is to just do a basic 'require'. This will look for an emacs library with the appropriate name and will read it in and evaluate it (it is like adding the file to your init file, so more lines to evaluate, which means increased load time for your init). The good thing about require is that it just loads the whole file and you know that everything gets evaluated. the bad things is that it can in turn require other files, which can require other files and can result in a much longer init time. To try and address this problem, emacs has the autoload facility. Basically, with autoload, you tell emacs that if it tries to execute a command with the name 'foo', it must first load (require) a specific file which you define in the autoload definition. The advantage here is that emacs doesn't try to load the library until you first try to use it, so there is no increase in load time. The disadvantage is that it can mean there is a delay the first time you use a command and it won't work if other parts of your init use the command (well, it will work, but will have no impact on improving load time).
4. Switch to use-pckage. There is a very useful package called use-package which can help address all of the issues I've mentioned. It helps compartmentalise your configuraiton, simplifies some common configuration tasks and has support for either setting up a package with autoloads or deferring the loading of a package until emacs is idle. It can help speed up your init time considerably provided you use it correctly. Highly recommend giving it a go. See https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package