# Speed up slow Emacs startup without full qualified domain name (FQDN)

Tags: emacs, elisp, startup

[Emacs takes unbelievably long to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619870/emacs-takes-unbelievably-long-to-start) without a fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

I would like to know what elisp commands in the .emacs file could speed it up without a FQDN e.g. using a fake system-name.

Comment: Upgrade to Emacs-25 where we got rid of the FQDN business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve this issue in `~/emacs` since the wait takes place before this file is even loaded.

Comment: Oh no. Then it really needs a change of the emacs code!

Comment: I've never run into this issue. I do remember some years back there were issues if your system networking wasn't correctly setup. Can someone clarify - for example, if I have a hostname of localhost.localnet, does this not suffice? If it does, can you not just do that to avoid the startup issue?